# telerik mvc grid image button

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a **telerik mvc grid** , server binding , each row has "*Select*" button ,
I want to let the button to has "*Image*"
I use the following definition but it doesn't work

```
columns.Command(commands => commands.Select().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)).Title("");
```

why?

another question , can I change the image of the button , if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was that , I put the style in a script in the header
solution : put the style in a script in the body

Answer (score 0):

You can give `.HtmlAttributes` your button like

```
columns.Command(commands => commands.Select().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Image)).HtmlAttributes(new { @class="btn"}).Title("");

//and you have to override the image with your class
.btn .t-icon{
    background-image: url('../../Images/img.png');
}
```